# Transposing a matrix in Prolog using decompose

Tags: prolog

My Test Case

```
trans([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], R).
R = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]] ;
No
```

Code i have written below to transpose my matrix

```
list_head_tail([H|T], H, T).
decompose(X, L1, L2) :-
   maplist(list_head_tail, X, L1, L2).

trans(X,[L1|R]):-
    decompose(X,L1,L2),
    trans(L2,R).
```

I know that we can approach this problem several ways. I would like to how i would fix the problem where my code is breaking below.

```
Exit: (8) decompose([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [1, 3, 5], [[2], [4], [6]]) ? creep
Call: (8) trans([[2], [4], [6]], _G15907) ? creep
```

Apparently the code breaks when i receive a list of lists. How do i handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `trans/2` always calls itself recursively until it fails. It is missing a base case. Perhaps try something like:

```
trans([[]|_], []).
```

Comment: After adding the rule I proposed to your code, this seems to work: `trans([[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,3],[2,4]])`. Are you expecting something different?